# What exactly is overlapping candidate key?

Tags: database-design, normalization, dependencies

Can some one please explain to me in simple terms what is `overlapping candidate key` ? What is `overlapping` as the name suggests?

Consider the below relation

```
R(L,M,N,O,P) 
{
    M -> O
    NO -> P
    P -> L
    L -> MN
}
```

Which of the above functional dependency is bringing in overlapping candidate key in the above relation ?

Lets restrict the discussion to dependencies, I'm not interested in BCNF at the moment

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're right on the money with the possible candidate keys, vikkyhacks. Overlapping candidate keys are composite (consist of more than one attribute) candidate keys with at least one attribute in common. So your overlapping candidate keys are NM and NO (they share N).

*Additional explanation of the above, originally left in comments:*

All overlapping candidate keys are groups of (e.g. two or more) candidate keys. That means the first criterion is that your relation `R` must have more than one candidate key (minimal super keys). For any of the candidate keys to be overlapping, each of them (again two or more) must meet a few additional conditions. 1) They both must be composite candidate keys. They must consist of more than one attribute, so a key like `A` will never be overlapping, but `AB` might overlap with another key. 2) The composite keys must share an attribute. `AB` overlaps with `AC` and `BD` but not `CD` or `EF`.

To summarize: two or more sets of attributes where 1) each set is a candidate key (minimal superkey) for the relation, 2) each set is a a composite key (consists of more than one attribute), and 3) one or more of the attributes of the composite keys overlaps with an attribute of another key in the set. So you can rule out `MNOP` and `NOPL` on the basis that they are not minimal superkeys. You can rule out `P` and `L` on the basis that they are not composite keys (they consist of one attribute). You're left with two keys, `NO` and `NM`, which share the attribute `N`, so you are finished.

#### Example

It may also help to have an example you can really wrap your head around. The only time I've ever seen where you will have overlapping candidate keys is when you have 1) two attributes that functionally determine one another (e.g. a one-to-one relationship between `A` and `B` where `A` has one `B` and `B` has one `A`) and 2) these attributes are part of composite candidate keys.

For example, in some system, a `Customer` has one `CreditCard`, and a `CreditCard` belongs to one `Customer`. In the Rentals table, you uniquely identify a `Rental` by the `EquipmentId`, `Date` and `CustomerId`. For convenience, you've stored `CreditCard` on this table as well.

This means that the following FDs hold:

```
{CustomerId, EquipmentId, Date} -> {CreditCard}
{CustomerId} -> {CreditCard}
```

But since the association is one-to-one, the following FDs also hold:

```
{CreditCard} -> {CustomerId}
{CreditCard, EquipmentId, Date} -> {CustomerId}
```

Since `CustomerId` and `CreditCard` can be used interchangeably to uniquely identify your customer.

In the scenario above, you have overlapping candidate keys:

```
{CreditCard, EquipmentId, Date}
{CustomerId, EquipmentId, Date}
```

They are overlapping because they are *composite* keys (they consist of more than one attribute) and because at least one of their attributes is shared (in this case, they share both `EquipmentId` and `Date`.

You said you don't care about `BCNF` at the moment, but to fully bring this home, the scenario above is the reason why you'll occasionally see a table that is in `3NF` but not `BCNF`. The table above is in `3NF`, but not `BCNF`.

`3NF` allows FDs where 1) the FD is trivial 2) the left side of the FD is a candidate key or 3) the right side of the FD is a key attribute (an attribute used to make any key). Since `CreditCard` and `CustomerId` are both key attributes, all FDs either meet 2 or 3.

`BCNF` is very similar, but it only allows conditions 1 and 2 allowed by `3NF`. Since the 3rd condition is not allowed by `BCNF`, and both `CID -> CC` and `CC -> CID` use condition 3, this table is not `BCNF`, but it is `3NF`.

For practical purposes, the case is fairly rare and this information is pedantic. The giveaway that your table has a problem will be the fact that `CreditCard/CustomerId` pairs are repeated across your table. You also may recognize that the table would not even be in `2NF` without this rare condition where the right side of an FD may be a key attribute because `CreditCard` is a partial dependency on the primary key (it depends on `CustomerId` but not `EquipmentId` or `Date`.

Comment: This is the best explanation I came across on 2NF/3NF vs BCNF

Answer (score 4):

A candidate key is a set of attributes that constitute a minimal superkey. Two candidate keys, A and B, are said to overlap if they have some attributes in common, i.e.: A ∩ B is non-empty. In your case, MN and NO would be overlapping candidate keys in R.

Because of the minimality (irreducibility) requirement one candidate key can never be a subset of another in the same relation. It follows that for two distinct candidate keys of a relation to overlap both must consist of more than one attribute, i.e.: for any pair of overlapping candidate keys A - (A ∩ B) must be non-empty and B - (A ∩ B) must be non-empty.

Answer (score 1):

The first three FD's combine to give

```
MNOP -> L
```

so MNOP is one possible candidate key, CK1.

Similarly the last three FD's combine to give

```
NOPL -> M
```

so NOPL is another possible candidate key, CK2.

However CK1 and CK2 have columns NOP in common, making them *overlapping* candidate keys.

Comment: NOPL and MNOP are super keys, the candidate keys possible are `P`,`L`, `NO`, and `NM` A super key qualifies as a candidate key only if does not have any minimal subset. Taking your example `MNOP` is super key because the minimal subset `P` in it can derive all the other attributes on the relation

Answer (score -1):

To check if a relation is having an overlapping Candidate key dependency:

Check if there is any dependency where a Complete Candidate key is determining a Part of Candidate key.
Then the OCK dependency holds